# How can I make a program overlay text on a postscript file?

Tags: pdf, graphics, shell, postscript, ghostscript

I have some graphs in postscript format, generated by gnuplot. I need to place some identifying information on the graph. How can I script some instructions to do that? I want to write a number at the top right corner of the graph (a .ps file).

Comment: Can you provide a link to a sample of your .ps graphs? (I have code, but it doesn't work with all types of PS.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, the example file you linked to is well behaving (and has not re-defined the `showpage` operator).

So I'm now assuming the following:

1. All your .ps files are similar to your example file.
2. All your .ps files are 1 page only (like .eps files).
3. All your filenames are like constructed as `gnp-NNN.ps` (like *gnp-544.ps* is).
4. The number you want to appear in the top right corner is `NNN` from the filename.

I also assume you have Ghostscript installed, and it is the [**most recent version**](http://www.ghostscript.com/releases/), 8.71. I'm currently on Windows -- if you're on Linux/Unix, just replace `gswin32c.exe` by `gs` and all line endings `^` by `\`.

### Test PDF Output

Now try this command first:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
 -o gnp-with-number-544.pdf ^
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
 -g5030x5320 ^
 -c "/Helvetica-Italic findfont 15 scalefont setfont 453 482 moveto (544) show" ^
 -f gnp-544.ps
```

and see if the resulting `gnp-with-number-544.pdf` looks like you want it.

The `-c "..."` is used to pass PostScript snippets to Ghostscript and make it process these together with the main .ps file which has then to follow as next parameter, with `-f ...`.

You can modify parameters:

- Replace the `/Helvetica-Italic` fontname by `/Helvetica`, `/Courier`, `/Times`, `Helvetica-Bold` or whatever you've available and prefer.
- Or modify the fontsize: `15` here means 15 points (in PDF *72 points == 1 inch*).
- Or change the position: `453 482` moves the PostScript currentpoint to *"453 points to the left, 482 points to the top"* (with the oringin *0,0* set to the bottom left corner).
- Or tweak the media size: `-g5030x5320` gives you 503x532 points (due to the default resolution of 720 dpi used by `-sDEVICE=pdfwrite`.
- Or set the string being printed to `(File No. 544) show` or whatever you want.

You could also add quite a few parameters to tweak the quality of the output file (resolution, font embedding etc.), but these ones will do for now.

### Change to PostScript Output

Should you need PostScript output for some reason instead of PDF, change the command like this:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
 -o gnp-with-number-544.ps ^
 -sDEVICE=ps2write ^
 -g5030x5320 ^
 -c "/Helvetica-Italic findfont 15 scalefont setfont 453 482 moveto (544) show" ^
 -f gnp-544.ps
```

### Batch-convert Lots of Files

Now, how to batch-convert this? For this last step, I'm assuming:

1. your `NNN` numbering scheme is not using leading `0`s.
2. your range of files to be converted is gnp-1.ps..gnp-1000.ps.
3. you want PDF output with the numbers added, not PS.

**On Windows**, create an `addnumbers-make-pdf.bat` file with this content:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
-o gnp-with-number-%1.pdf ^
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
-g5030x5320 ^
-c "/Helvetica-Italic findfont 15 scalefont setfont 453 482 moveto (%1) show" ^
-f gnp-%1.ps
```

Now run this command in a `cmd.exe` console:

```
for /l %i in (1,1,100) do (addnumbers-make-pdfvim.bat %i)
```

**On Linux**, create an `addnumbers-make-pdf.sh` Bash shell script with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash
gs \
-o gnp-with-number-${1}.pdf \
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
-g5030x5320 \
-c "/Helvetica-Italic findfont 15 scalefont setfont 453 482 moveto (${1}) show" \
-f gnp-${1}.ps
```

Now run this command in a shell:

```
for i in $(seq 1 1000); do addnumbers-make-pdf.sh ${i} ; done
```

---

**Update:**
Hah!, it even works ;-)  I just tested it on Windows. Here is a screenshot with the original and the overlayed file (as PDFs):
[image]

Comment: i want to do add footer in a pdf file with x pages. overlay text using ghostscript please help. i tried libreoffice to convert pdf to doc using MS Word 2007 XML but got empty document. any help will be great

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have access to the Gnuplot source file, here is a generic method that works (which you can script). It uses **Ghostscript** and **PDFTK**.

1. Create a new PDF file that contains the content you want to overlay to your .ps graphs.
2. Convert your Gnuplot-originating .ps graphs to PDF using Ghostscript.
3. Use `pdftk` (on Unix) or `pdftk.exe` (on Windows) to overlay the two PDFs.
4. Use Ghostscript to convert the PDF back to PS (if you need that), or just continue using the PDF.

[This SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/171790/print-pdf-file-with-file-path-in-footer/173127#173127) contains many details which will help you along the path outlined above.

---

With the help of a **text editor** you may be able to insert PostScript code that render the additional information into your .ps files manually.

However, I cannot give you a working PS code snippet without seeing the graph's PS code first.

---

**Ghostscript** you may be able to create new PS files from your graphs using a single commandline.

Try it with s.th. similar to `gs -sDEVICE=ps2write -o output-with-comments-gnuplot.ps -c "570 800 moveto /Helvetica findfont 32 scalefont setfont (Number: 42) show" -f /path/to/gnuplot.ps`".

However, I cannot really tell if this PS code snippet would really work without seeing the graph's PS code first.

Comment: I did go through those answers on SuperUser but was looking for a more direct approach, which you say could be done if one has access to the graph ps source. Sorry for the delay, so here it is : http://terminal9.org/.files/gnp-544.ps

Answer (score 1):

If you can affect the gnuplot code, you can add the text with gnuplot. See [this](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/enhancedtext.html) for example. The command to use is [set label](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/label2-e.html).